# Using gsap.set() in React

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I am new to React and creating my first GSAP animation with it, a collapsible sidebar. In the past (not using React), I have set the menu off screen using gsap.set() and would then toggle the menu open and close by animating the horizontal x value. I have my animation running in React, but have been unable to determine the initial placement of gsap.set(). Without setting that value first, the menu is seen closing on page load (and then the toggle works fine from there). I have been unable to find any instruction on the web on how to use gsap.set() in React. Can I get a little help?

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { FaBars } from "react-icons/fa";
const SideMenu = () => {
   const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
   const animation = useRef(null);
   const wrapper = useRef(null);
   const linksContainer = useRef(null);
   const style = { fill: "#3399ff", width: "25px", height: "25px", border: "none", marginTop: 
   "-11px", marginRight: "6px" };

   useEffect(() => {
       animation.current = gsap.timeline().to(wrapper.current, {
      x: "101%",
      duration: 1,
    });

    return () => {
      animation.current.kill();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (menuOpen) {
      animation.current.reverse();
    } else {
      animation.current.play();
    }
 }, [menuOpen]);

  return (
    <aside>
      <button className="hamburger" onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)}>
        <FaBars style={style} />
      </button>

      <div className="wrapper" ref={wrapper}>
        <ul className="links-container" ref={linksContainer}>
          <li>
            <a href="#" className="link">
              Menu Item
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
  );
};
```

Comment: You can set it inside the first `useEffect`, or try 
https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect